# Install R package in Jupyter

Tags: r, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook

I have been trying over the weekend to install `mosaic`, `car` and some other packages on an R kernel (3.4.2) in Jupyter Notebook running Ubuntu 16.04. I have tried `install.packages('car', '/home/jayaramdas/anaconda3/lib/R/library/', repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')`: it returns:
also installing the dependency ‘pbkrtest’

`Warning message in install.packages("car", "/home/jayaramdas/anaconda3/lib/R/library/", :
“installation of package ‘pbkrtest’ had non-zero exit status”Warning message in install.packages("car", "/home/jayaramdas/anaconda3/lib/R/library/", :
“installation of package ‘car’ had non-zero exit status”`

I've tried installing it in the original R package and I get this:
`Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("car", "/home/jayaramdas/anaconda3/lib/R/library/",  :
  installation of package ‘pbkrtest’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("car", "/home/jayaramdas/anaconda3/lib/R/library/",  :
  installation of package ‘car’ had non-zero exit status`

I tried using Rstudio to install it, but it won't let me write the file. I also tried downloading the zip file for Ubuntu and it still gave the 'non-zero exit`error.  Is this a usual problem that people have with`car` and other R packages? I am just trying to figure how to add some packages to my jupyter notebook.

Comment: Can we see the full error log?

Comment: @Daruchini: I just updated the post to reflect some of the feedback I am getting.

Comment: Check to make sure you have `pbkrtest` installed or try and install the packages with `dependancies = T`

Answer (score 1):

You are on Ubuntu. You want to use a package manager (`conda`).

May I suggest you use the *native* one?

```
sudo apt-get install r-cran-car
```

*will* install `car` and all its dependencies.  If not, file an Ubuntu bug report.

Similarly, you can get *many* more packages from Ubuntu: `apt-cache search 'r-cran-*'`.  And once you consider the Rutter PPAs you have a large part of CRAN prebuilt.

Comment: should I run the above from `cd  ~/anaconda`?

Comment: Does not matter -- it will install the `car` package as part of the standard Ubuntu system.  And for what it is worth I also run Jupyter without recourse to `conda`. YMMV.  But you have choices.  Good luck,

Comment: I was able to get the installation to work. But, now when I fire up a jupyter browser and run `install.packages("car"):` I get a `installing 
Warning message in install.packages("car"):
“installation of package ‘minqa’ had non-zero exit status”Warning :
 message in install.packages("car"):
“installation of package ‘car’ had non-zero exit status” error.`                  If I run `library(car)` then I get this error: `Error in library("car"): there is no package called ‘car’
Traceback:

1. library("car")
2. stop(txt, domain = NA)`